# Create variant without parameter from an empty tuple

Tags: rust

I want to be able to construct enum values by giving the variant constructor a value:

```
use self::Variants::*;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Variants {
    Unit(()),
    One(u8),
}

fn emit<C: Fn(S) -> T, S, T>(constructor: C, value: S) -> T {
    constructor(value)
}

fn main() {
    let unit: Variants = emit(&Unit, ());
    println!("{:?}", unit); // Prints Unit(()).
    let one: Variants = emit(&One, 10);
    println!("{:?}", one); // Prints One(10).
}
```

The issue with this example is that I need `()` in `Unit(())` instead of the more normal `Unit` (without parameter).

I tried using specialization:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Constructor<S, T> {
    fn construct(self, value: S) -> T;
}

impl<T> Constructor<(), T> for T {
    fn construct(self, _value: ()) -> T {
        self
    }
}

impl<F: Fn(S) -> T, S, T> Constructor<S, T> for F {
    default fn construct(self, value: S) -> T {
        self(value)
    }
}

fn emit<C: Constructor<I, R>, I, R>(callback: &C, value: I) -> R {
    callback.construct(value)
}

use self::Variants::*;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Variants {
    Unit,
    One(u8),
}

fn main() {
    let unit: Variants = emit(&Unit, ());
    println!("{:?}", unit); // Should prints Unit.
    let one: Variants = emit(&One, 10);
    println!("{:?}", one); // Prints One(10).
}
```

but this fails at compile time with:

```
conflicting implementations of trait `Constructor<(), _>`:
```

From my understanding of the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), this fails because no one of these `impl`s is a subset of the other. I think it is because the `T` in `for T` of the first `impl` is more generic than the `F` of the `for F` of the second implementation. Hence, it cannot be the specialization.

On the other hand, it cannot be the general (`default`) implementation because `Constructor<(), T> for T` (and even `Constructor<S, T> for T`) is more specific than `Constructor<S, T> for F` because `T` is written twice in the former.

This is my understanding from reading the RFC. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

How could I make the first example work without having to give a useless parameter to `Unit`?

I am open to solutions that require the nightly compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about implementing `Fn` for `Variants`? (Note: `Fn` requires `FnMut` and `FnMut` requires `FnOnce`, so we have to implement all three.)

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

use self::Variants::*;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Variants {
    Unit,
    One(u8),
}

impl FnOnce<((),)> for Variants {
    type Output = Variants;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: ((),)) -> Self::Output {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl FnMut<((),)> for Variants {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: ((),)) -> Self::Output {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl Fn<((),)> for Variants {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, _: ((),)) -> Self::Output {
        self.clone()
    }
}

fn emit<C: Fn(S) -> T, S, T>(callback: &C, value: S) -> T {
    callback(value)
}

fn main() {
    let unit: Variants = emit(&Unit, ());
    println!("{:?}", unit); // Prints Unit.
    let one: Variants = emit(&One, 10);
    println!("{:?}", one); // Prints One(10).
}
```

The only weird aspect of this solution is that you could now pass values such as `&One(10)` as the first argument to `emit` (though the second argument could only be `()`).